# How can I reference a named stylesheet in the className value?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to use classes in my component for the first time. From tutorial I watched from Academind but I couldn't get what I want. I created my css file via; Good.module.css, this's the error d not found:Error:can't resolve './component/layout/Good.module.css.

This's the code:

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Classes from './Components/layout/Good.module.css';

function NavBar(){
    return(
      <`header className = {todo}>
         `<nav>
            `<li><Link path='/home'>Home<Link><li>`
           </nav>`

       </header>`
)
}
```

I tried wrapping the classes in a curly braces while importing, but that seems not to be the solution.
And the error is still showing up, I expect using classes, I will scope the classNames of each file is to be  unique
to avoid crsahing with other element in other file.

Comment: Can you share your file structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the module you're importing is in the same dir as the component,

```
import styles from './button.module.css'

const Button = () => {
   return (
      <div className={styles.main}>
         <button className={styles.btn}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
   );

}
```

And then in your button.module.css file:

```
.main {
  height: 50px;
}

.btn {
   color: green;
}
```